# Maximizing expectation of gaussian process over covariance matrix with fixed trace

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, gaussian

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{\Sigma \in PSD_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}), \wedge \forall i,\Sigma_{ii}=1\}$. Then $\mathcal{A} \subset M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is convex, closed, and bounded.

For each $\Sigma \in \mathcal{A}$, let $X_{\Sigma} \sim N(0, \Sigma). $

Let $f_{1}(\Sigma):=\mathbb{E}[\max_{1 \leq i\leq n}(X_{\Sigma})_{i}]$, and let $f_{2}(\Sigma):=\mathbb{E}[\max_{1 \leq i\leq n}|(X_{\Sigma})_{i}|]$. Both $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are convex functions on $\mathcal{A}$. By the extreme value theorem they attain a maximum and minium on $\mathcal{A}$. How can the extremes of $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ be characterized?

Answer (score 3):

1. The maximizer over $\Sigma$'s
   with nonnegative entries is $\Sigma=I_n$.

This follows from [Slepian's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slepian%27s_lemma) and the formula
$$EZ=\int_0^\infty dz\,P(Z>z)-\int_{-\infty}^0 dz\,P(Z<z), \tag{1}\label{1}$$
which holds if $Z$ is a random variable with $E|Z|<\infty$.

Indeed, by Slepian's lemma, if $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ are zero-mean Gaussian random vectors with $EX_i^2=EY_i^2$ for all $i$ and $EX_i X_j\le EY_i Y_j$ for all distinct $i,j$, then $P(\max_i X_i>z)\ge P(\max_i Y_i>z)$ for all real $z$ and, equivalently, $P(\max_i X_i<z)\le P(\max_i Y_i<z)$ for all real $z$. So, the claimed result follows immediately from \eqref{1}.

---

2. If the $X_i$'s are exchangeable, then, similarly, the maximizer is the $\Sigma$ with all off-diagonal entries equal $-\frac1{n-1}$ (for $n\ge2$).

Indeed, in this case $\Sigma=\frac1{1-c}(I_n-c1_n1_n^\top)$ for some real $c\ne1$, where $1_n:=[1,\dots,1]^\top$, and the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are $\frac1{1-c}$ (of multiplicity $n-1$) and $\frac{1-cn}{1-c}$. So, $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite iff $c\le\frac1n$ iff the off-diagonal entries $-\frac c{1-c}$ of $\Sigma$ are $\ge-\frac1{n-1}$. So, the claim for exchangeable $X_i$'s follows by \eqref{1} and Slepian's lemma.

**Comment:** It follows from the [answer by Guillaume Aubrun](https://mathoverflow.net/a/430414/36721) that, remarkably, the exchangeability condition can be dropped -- in view of a recent proof of the longstanding simplex mean width conjecture (of which I had not known).

Comment: I am very surprised by this answer, although I am not surprised by Slepian's lemma. My guess, is that when $n$ is even, the maximum will be achieved when $X_1,...,X_{n/2}$ are i.i.d. and $(X_{n/2+1},...,X_n)=-(X_1,...,X_{n/2})$. For example, $E[\max(X_1,-X_1)] = \sqrt{2/\pi}$ whereas  $E[\max(X_1,X_2)]=\sqrt{1/\pi}$ for $X_1,X_2$ i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan : I can provide details on the use of Slepian's lemma a bit later. As for your example for $n=2$, it is covered by the last sentence in the current version of the answer. Otherwise, I have only considered $\Sigma$'s 
with nonnegative entries -- you may have overlooked that.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan : I have added details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the discussion.

Comment: Just to be clear, the global maximizer is the solution you present in the exchangeable case, correct? The maximizer must be exchangeable because max is invariant under re-labelling.

Comment: This problem whether, without assuming exchangeability a priori, the maximum is achieved for the covariance matrix with off-diagonal entries equal to $-1/(n-1)$ is known as the simplex mean width conjecture. A solution has been recently announced by Aaron Goldsmith in the preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.03393

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis. In the question, $\Sigma$ is assumed to be positive definite (positive semi-definite would be better for $f$ to have a maximum and not only a least upper bound), and not to have non-negative entries.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan : It is convenient to allow $\Sigma$ to be positive semidefinite, as you did in your example. In the first part of my answer (above the horizontal line), it was indeed explicitly assumed that all the entries of $\Sigma$ are nonnegative.

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun : Wow, a longstanding problem! However, it is not immediately clear to me that the problem in the OP is equivalent to (or is a particular case of) the simplex mean width problem. Can you explain this, perhaps in a formal answer?

Comment: @colin : It is unclear to me that a "maximizer must be exchangeable because max is invariant under re-labelling". According to Guillaume Aubrun's comment, this had been a longstanding problem. Cf. e.g. this: the maximum of $x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$ over all $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in[0,\infty)^n$ with $x_1+\cdots+x_n=1$ is attained only when exactly one of the $x_i$'s is $1$, rather than when the $x_i$'s are equal to one another.

Comment: @colin Can we have a good statement of the problem? If $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is assumed to be a gaussian centered vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ , write it explicitely. The assumption positive definite should be relaxed into positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopheLeuridan, I have edited the post.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you. I see the analogy and will think about this.

Comment: @IosifPinelis for the relation between the simplex mean width conjecture and the question mentioned here, see Conjecture 1.4 in http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~alexandr/OrganizedPapers/AL-simp-wv.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I assume all random variables are centered. It is clear that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are minimized when $\Sigma_{ij}=1$, i.e., the Gaussian vector is distributed as $(X,X,\dots,X)$ with $X \sim N(0,1)$.

The maximization problem is more interesting. The same question has been asked already some years ago: [Maximum of the expectation of maximum of Gaussian variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161002/maximum-of-the-expectation-of-maximum-of-gaussian-variables/161015#161015)

The fact that $f_2$ is maximized for $\Sigma = \mathrm{Id}$ follows from the Khatri-Sidak lemma. The fact that $f_1$ is maximized for $\Sigma_{ij} = -1/(n-1)$ is a long-standing conjecture known as the simplex mean width conjecture ; see [www.math.ualberta.ca/~alexandr/OrganizedPapers/AL-simp-wv.pdf](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Ealexandr/OrganizedPapers/AL-simp-wv.pdf) for many equivalent formulations.

A solution to this conjecture has been announced in https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.03393 . That paper looks correct to me!