# Subgaussian norm of a symmetric $\{-1,0,1\}$ random variable

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions

Let $p\in [0,1/2]$, and define $\xi$ as the symmetric random variable such that
$$
\xi = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ w.p. } p\\
0 & \text{ w.p. } 1-2p\\
-1 & \text{ w.p. } p
\end{cases}
$$
so that $\mathbb{E}[\xi]=0$, $\mathbb{E}[\xi^2]=2p$, and for $p=1/2$ $\xi$ is just a Rademacher r.v.

I am interested in tight (but manageable/usable) bounds on the subgaussian parameter of $\xi$, as a function of $p$ (and, if possible, references to cite directly). In particular, $\xi$ is always $1$-subgaussian, but what can we say for $p\to 0$?

he MGF of $\xi$ is easy to calculate as
$$
\mathbb{E} e^{t\xi} =  1+2p(\cosh t - 1), \qquad t\geq 0
$$
so it boils down to studying the quantity
$$
\kappa(p) = \sup_{t> 0}\frac{\log(1+2p(\cosh t - 1))}{t^2}
$$

The case of a binary random variable (Bernoulli) was given in [Theorem 2.1, 1]. Is the analogue for the above symmetrized version known?

*[1] Buldigīn, V. V.; Moskvichova, K. K. Sub-Gaussian norm of a binary random variable. (Ukrainian) ; translated from Teor. Ĭmovīr. Mat. Stat. No. 86 (2011), 28--42 Theory Probab. Math. Statist. No. 86, (2013), 33--49* [[pdf]](https://www.ams.org/journals/tpms/2013-86-00/S0094-9000-2013-00887-4/S0094-9000-2013-00887-4.pdf)

Comment: Isn't there a missing log in the numerator?

Comment: Whoops. Not anymore, thanks!

Comment: Numerically, it appears that the subgaussian constant behaves something like
$1/(2\log(1/p))$ -- which is qualitatively similar to what you get in Kearns-Saul for small p.

Comment: you can even replace the 1/2 by 1/4, and that appears to be tight.

Comment: @ClementC. : It is not a good idea to use a Gaussian bound here for small $p$. Then the distribution (say $\mu_\xi$) of $\xi$ has rather heavy tails (say in the sense that the moments of $\xi$ grow relatively fast), and $\mu_\xi$ is much better approximated by a symmetrized Poisson distribution.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Cf. e.g. the Bennett--Hoeffding bound [(formula (2.9))](https://redirect.cs.umbc.edu/~lomonaco/f08/643/hwk643/Hoeffding.pdf) and its refinements, such as [this one](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.1214/12-AIHP495.pdf), involving a  "balanced" convolution of a Gaussian distribution and a Poisson distribution, thus covering well, in your case, all values of $p$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you! My end goal was to bound the expectation of the maximum of $n$ such things with a $\sqrt{\log n}$ dependence, hence the use of subgaussianity. I'll have a look at the second reference you linked.

Comment: @ClementC. : "to bound the expectation of the maximum of $n$
 such things with a $\sqrt{\log n}$ dependence" ... With what scaling? (Without scaling, it is obviously bounded by $1$.) Anyhow, because of the mentioned heavy tails for small $p$, I don't think you can get a Gaussian-like $\sqrt{\log n}$ rate of growth. On the other hand, if you are only interested in the best rate up to universal constant factor that you can get from the sub-Gaussianity, then my answer (and apparently fedja's too) should do, even for small $p$, because it gives you $\kappa(p)$ up to the factor $2$.

Answer (score 8):

$\newcommand\ka\kappa\newcommand\la\lambda$Let us show that
\begin{equation*}
    \ka(p)=p\quad\text{for }p\in[1/6,1/2]. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}

Indeed, suppose that $p\in[1/6,1/2]$. Write
\begin{equation*}
    \ka(p) = \sup_{t>0}f_p(t), 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    f_p(t):=\frac{\ln(1-2p+2p\cosh t)}{t^2}.
\end{equation*}
For real $t>0$, let
\begin{equation*}
    g_p(t):=f'_p(t)\frac{t^3}2=\frac{pt\sinh t}{1-2p+2p\cosh t}-\ln(1-2p+2p\cosh t). 
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    h_p(t)&:=g'_p(t)\frac{(1-2p+2p\cosh t)^2}p \\ 
    &=t \cosh t-\sinh t-4 p (t+\sinh t) \sinh ^2\frac t2
    \\ 
&   \le h_{1/6}(t)=-\sum_{k\ge2}\frac{2^{2k+1}-8k}{6(2k+1)!}\,t^{2k+1}<0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
so that $g_p(t)$ is decreasing (in $t>0$). Also, $g_p(0+)=0$. So, $g_p(t)<0$ (for $t>0$) and hence $f_p(t)$ is decreasing (in $t>0$). So,
\begin{equation*}
    \ka(p) = f_p(0+)=p,
\end{equation*}
which proves \eqref{1}.

---

For $p\in(0,1/6]$, a quick bound on $\ka(p)$ can be obtained from the Kearns--Saul inequality -- see e.g. [inequality (1.1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4496.pdf), which states that the subgaussian constant for a centered Bernoulli random variable (r.v.) $X$ with parameter $r\in(0,1)$ is no greater than (actually, is equal to)
\begin{equation*}
    c(r):=\frac{1-2r}{4\ln(1/r-1)}. 
\end{equation*}
Note that, if $p\in(0,1/4]$, $X$ is as above, $Y$ is an independent copy of $X$, and $r=r_p:=\frac12-\sqrt{\frac14-p}$, then $X-Y$ will equal your r.v. $\xi$ in distribution. It follows that for $p\in(0,1/6]$
\begin{equation*}
    \ka(p)\le2c(r_p). \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, by Jensen's inequality for the convex function $y\mapsto e^y$, we have $Ee^{t\xi}=Ee^{t(X-Y)}\ge Ee^{tX}=e^{c(r_p)t^2}$ for some $t>0$ depending on $p$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \ka(p)\ge c(r_p). \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
So, by \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}, for all $p\in(0,1/6]$ the subgaussian constant $\ka(p)$ differs from $c(r_p)$ by a factor in the interval $[1,2]$.

This is illustrated by the graph $\Big\{\dfrac{\ka(p)}{c(r_p)}\colon0<p<1/6\Big\}$ below:

[image]

---

**Added:**
The OP [wrote](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451743/subgaussian-norm-of-a-symmetric-1-0-1-random-variable/451752#comment1168374_451743): "My end goal was to bound the expectation of the maximum of $n$ such things with a $\sqrt{\log n}$ dependence" ... What is meant here concerning a $\sqrt{\log n}$ dependence is apparently the following: If $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$ are standard normal random variables (r.v.'s), [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89147/96609)
\begin{equation*}
    E\max_1^n\xi_i=O(\sqrt{\ln n}), \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}
and, [moreover](https://mathoverflow.net/a/161015/36721), $E\max_1^n\xi_i\asymp\sqrt{\ln n}$ if $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$ are *independent* standard normal  r.v.'s.

However, in contrast with the normal distribution, for small $p$ the distribution of the r.v. $\xi$ as in the OP has rather heavy tails (say in the sense that the absolute moments of $\xi$ grow relatively fast). So, the very slow growth of the expected maximum (as in \eqref{4}) will not be the case with these heavy tails. E.g., if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent copies of the standardized r.v. $\xi$ in distribution, then
\begin{equation*}
    E\max_1^n X_i=\frac{1-(1-p)^n-p^n}{\sqrt{2p}}
    \sim n\sqrt{p/2} \quad \\ 
    \text{if $n\to\infty$ and $np\to0$,}   \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation*}
so that $E\max_1^n X_i$ grows asymptotically linearly with $n$ in this regime.

If now $n\to\infty$ and $np\to\la\in(0,\infty)$ (the symmetrized Poisson regime), then $E\max_1^n X_i\sim C_\la\, \sqrt n$ with $C_\la:=(1-e^{-\la})/\sqrt{2\la}$, still a much faster rate of growth than $\sqrt{\ln n}$. We can also write
\begin{equation*}
    E\max_1^n X_i
    \sim C_\la n\sqrt{p/\la} \quad\text{if $n\to\infty$ and $np\to\la\in(0,\infty)$}.  \tag{6}\label{6} 
\end{equation*}

All this indicates that it is not a good idea to use a (sub)Gaussian bound for the distribution of the r.v. $\xi$ as in the OP if $p$ is small. Instead, letting then $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be any (not necessarily independent) copies of the standardized r.v. $\xi$ in distribution, we can simply write
\begin{equation*}
    E\max_1^n X_i\le E\sum_1^n \max(0,X_i)=n\sqrt{p/2},  
\end{equation*}
which agrees well with the independent-case asymptotics in \eqref{5} and \eqref{6}.

Answer (score 7):

For these matters, I usually rely on the following trickery:
$$
2\cosh t-2=\int_0^t (e^s-e^{-s})\,ds\le \int_0^t 2s e^s\,ds
\\
\le\int_0^t 2se^{as^2+\frac 1{4a}}\,ds=\frac 1a e^{\frac 1{4a}}[e^{at^2}-1]\,,
$$
so if $p=ae^{- \frac 1{4a}}$, we have
$$
e^{at^2}\ge 1+2p(\cosh t-1)
$$
for all $t$.

This is short and guaranteed for all $p$, as well as agrees with Areah's sharp asymptotics as $p\to 0$ though it is about twice off for only moderately small $p$. There are sharper bounds, of course, but they aren't quite one liners.

Comment: This is very nice!