# Is this inequality in two variables true?

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

It it true that for all $p\in(0,1/3]$ and all real $t$ we have
$$4  
\ln(1-p +p\cosh t)
\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-2p}}{1-\sqrt{1-2p}}
\le t^2 (1+c p) \sqrt{1-2p} ,$$
where $c:=2\sqrt{3}\, \ln(2+\sqrt{3})-3$?

If true, this inequality will provide an answer to this [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/451743/36721).

Comment: Both sides are even in $t$, so we only need to consider the problem for $t\geq 0$. I am thinking of the simpler problem with $p$ fixed: There is equality at $t=0$. And the inequality is strict for large enough $t$, as the right side behaves like $t^2$ while the left side is about $t$. So, it is enough to prove the inequality for small $t$.

Comment: @Medo : Yes, the problem seems to be mainly with intermediate values of $t$.

Comment: Dare I ask where that inequality came from?

Comment: @DanielAsimov : I have added this information.

Comment: @Medo: Of course we only need to consider $t \geq 0$. But the problem is not to prove the inequality for small $t$ but for very small $p$, for instance $p = 1e-10$. Indeed, a simple plot shows that the difference first is increasing in $t$, then downcreasing to a very small positive value (about $t =46$) and then increaing.

Answer (score 1):

*Remarks*: I hope this is a beginning for overcoming the challenge. It is valid for larger interval of the values of $p$ (and $t$) if we use more terms of Taylor approximation.

**Partial answer** for $p \in (1/11, 1/3]$ and $0 \le t < 2$

We have
\begin{align*}
    &\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2p}}\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-2p}}{1-\sqrt{1-2p}}\\[6pt]
    \le{}& \frac{c + 3}{2} + \frac{c - 3}{2}(3p - 1) + \frac{3(c-1)}{4}(3p-1)^2
    + \frac{5c - 9}{4}(3p - 1)^3\\[6pt]
    &\qquad + \frac{35c - 51}{16}(3p - 1)^4 
    + \frac{3}{20}(105c - 169)(3p - 1)^5. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
(*Note*: RHS is related to the 5-th Taylor approximation of LHS around $p = 1/3$. The proof is easy by using the substitution $1-2p = x^2/3$ and taking derivative.)

We have, for all $t \in [0, 2)$,
$$\cosh t \le 1 + \frac12 t^2 + \frac{1}{24}t^4 + \frac{7}{4680}t^6. \tag{2}$$
(*Note*: RHS is related to the 6-th Taylor approximation of LHS around $t = 0$. The proof is omitted here.)

Using (2), we have
$$\ln(1 - p + p\cosh t)
\le \ln\left (1 - p + p \left(1 + \frac12 t^2 + \frac{1}{24}t^4 + \frac{7}{4680}t^6\right)\right). \tag{3}$$

We have
\begin{align*}
    &\ln\left (1 - p + p \left(1 + \frac12 t^2 + \frac{1}{24}t^4 + \frac{7}{4680}t^6\right)\right)\\
    \le{}& \ln\left(1 + \frac16 t^2 + \frac{1}{72}t^4 + \frac{7}{14040}t^6\right)
    + \frac{\frac{1}{2}t^2 + \frac{1}{24}t^4 + \frac{7}{4680}t^6}{1 + \frac16 t^2 + \frac{1}{72}t^4 + \frac{7}{14040}t^6}(p - 1/3). \tag{4}
\end{align*}
(*Note*: RHS is the first order Taylor approximation of LHS around $p = 1/3$. The proof is easy by noting that LHS is concave in $p$.)

We have, for all $t \in [0, 2]$,
$$\ln\left(1 + \frac16 t^2 + \frac{1}{72}t^4 + \frac{7}{14040}t^6\right) \le \frac16 t^2. \tag{5}$$
(*Note*: The proof is easy by taking derivative.)

From (3)-(5), we have
$$
    \ln(1 - p + p\cosh t)
    \le \frac16t^2 + \frac{\frac{1}{2}t^2 + \frac{1}{24}t^4 + \frac{7}{4680}t^6}{1 + \frac16 t^2 + \frac{1}{72}t^4 + \frac{7}{14040}t^6}(p - 1/3). \tag{6}
$$

Using (1) and (6), it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
    &4\left(\frac16t^2 + \frac{\frac{1}{2}t^2 + \frac{1}{24}t^4 + \frac{7}{4680}t^6}{1 + \frac16 t^2 + \frac{1}{72}t^4 + \frac{7}{14040}t^6}(p - 1/3)\right)\\[6pt]
    &\times \left(\frac{c + 3}{2} + \frac{c - 3}{2}(3p - 1) + \frac{3(c-1)}{4}(3p-1)^2
    + \frac{5c - 9}{4}(3p - 1)^3\right.\\[6pt]
    &\qquad\quad \left. + \frac{35c - 51}{16}(3p - 1)^4 
    + \frac{3}{20}(105c - 169)(3p - 1)^5\right)\\
    &\le t^2(1 + cp). \tag{7}
\end{align*}

From $p \in (1/11, 1/3]$ and $t \in [0, 2)$, we parameterize them as follows
$$p = \frac{1}{11}\cdot \frac{u}{1 + u} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + u}, \quad u \ge 0$$
and
$$t = \frac{2v}{1 + v}, \quad v \ge 0.$$

(7) is equivalent to
$$F(u, v) \ge 0$$
where $F(u, v)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients.
This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis You are welcome.